# Angular create dynamic navbar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, partial-views

I am writing an app and I would like to have dynamic navbar. I created two separate partials with navbar for logged and guest user. In my index.html I created section where the navbar will be.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    <div class="navbar-inner">

    </div>
    <!-- /navbar-inner -->
</div>
```

Navbar controller should decide with one partial should be rendered. I check there if user is authenticated or not. But I don't know how to render partial from controller. Thanks for all answers and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have your logic in your Navbar controller which would assign, say `$scope.nav_partial_url` the proper value (partials/navbar.html or partials/navbar_loggedin.html) based on whether the user is logged in or not. In your view you'd use [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    <div class="navbar-inner">

        <div ng-include="nav_partial_url"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- /navbar-inner -->
</div>
```